# Crash when attempting to return a pybind11::array_t from c++ to python

Tags: python, c++, numpy, pybind11

I have created the following example library:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/numpy.h>

namespace py = pybind11;

struct Foo
{
    using UintArr = py::array_t<std::uint64_t, py::array::c_style | py::array::forcecast>;

    UintArr get() const
    {
        std::vector<std::uint64_t> v = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        return UintArr(v.size(), v.data());
    }
};

PYBIND11_MODULE(foo, m)
{
    py::class_<Foo>(m, "Foo")
        .def(py::init<>())
        .def("get",
             [](const Foo& t)
             {
                 py::gil_scoped_release release;
                 return t.get();
             });
}
```

In python, when I attempt to call `get` it crashes

```py
import foo
f = foo.Foo()
foo.get()           <--- crashes here
```

If I look at the core file with gdb I can see it's crashing on an import of `numpy.core.multiarray`

```py
#0 ... in PyImport_Import ()
#1 ... in PyImport_ImportModule ()
#2 ... in pybind11::module_::import (name=0x7f369e4c65de "numpy.core.multiarray") at /usr/include/pybind11/pybind11.h:1195
#3 ... in pybind11::detail::npy_api::lookup () at /usr/include/pybind11/numpy.h:264
#4 ... in pybind11::detail::npy_api::get () at /usr/include/pybind11/numpy.h:193
#5 ... in pybind11::detail::npy_format_descriptor<unsigned long, void>::dtype () at /usr/include/pybind11/numpy.h:1285
#6 ... in pybind11::dtype::of<unsigned long> () at /usr/include/pybind11/numpy.h:584
#7 ... in pybind11::array::array<unsigned long> (this=0x7ffed48a2548, shape=..., strides=..., ptr=0x560d3412b5a0, base=...) at /usr/include/pybind11/numpy.h:763
#8 ... in pybind11::array_t<unsigned long, 17>::array_t (this=0x7ffed48a2548, count=6, ptr=0x560d3412b5a0, base=...) at /usr/include/pybind11/numpy.h:1070
#9 ... in Foo::get (this=0x560d341285b0) at /home/steve.lorimer/src/python/example/pybind.cpp:15
```

I have confirmed that `numpy.core.multiarray` exists and that I am able to import it in python.

```py
import numpy.core.multiarray
numpy.core.multiarray.__file__
'/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.py'
```

What is happening here, and how can I return my numpy array to python from C++?

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the use of `py::gil_scoped_release` to release the GIL, which is then asserted during the `PyImport_Import`.

One could either remove the `py::gil_scoped_release` altogether, or reacquire it when creating the `py::array_t`

```
struct Foo
{
    using UintArr = py::array_t<std::uint64_t, py::array::c_style | py::array::forcecast>;

    UintArr get() const
    {
        std::vector<std::uint64_t> v = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        py::gil_scoped_acquire acquire; // reacquire GIL before calling py::array_t ctor
        return UintArr(v.size(), v.data());
    }
};

PYBIND11_MODULE(foo, m)
{
    py::class_<Foo>(m, "Foo")
        .def(py::init<>())
        .def("get",
             [](const Foo& t)
             {
                 py::gil_scoped_release release; // GIL released, presumably because Foo::get takes a long time
                 return t.get();
             });
}
```